# git rebase is not catching conflicts

Tags: git

For some reason when I try to rebase a branch with master with one file change (the pom.xml) git is not catching conflicts.

Here is the use case.

```
<Assume I have a master for my project already cloned and I'm in my master branch>
<Assume pom.xml in master has version 1.0>

// create branch
$ git checkout -b whatever

<modify the pom.xml in whatever branch to version 1.1>

// add..checkin and rebaseline
$ git commit -a -m 'whatever'
$ git rebase master

Current branch whatever is up to date.
```

At this point there are conflicts but git is saying the branch is up to date.  What am I missing here?  Shouldn't it report back with conflicts on the pom.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not understanding how this is supposed to conflict. If master already has 1.0 and then you check out from there and create a new commit to bump it to 1.1, then rebase the master branch on top of this new branch, there will be no changes to apply.

Unless `master` changes the version to something completely different and then you rebase that branch, you won't see any conflicts.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. Thanks for the response and for clarifying.